# MySQL delete records containing NaN

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with a column "A" that has NaN values in it. How do you update them? I have tried

```
update myTable set A = 0 where A is NaN;
```

But it gives me a syntax error. How do I query for NaN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use one of the following:

```
update myTable 
set A = 0 
where A = 'NaN';
```

OR

```
update myTable 
set A = 0 
where A LIKE '%NaN%';
```

Comment: @tadman they did not specify the datatype on the column, I am guessing a string.  But I MySQL allows LIKE syntax on numeric datatypes - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89c01/1

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 update myTable set A = 0 where A = 'NaN';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
update myTable set A = '0' where A = 'NaN'
```